# How execution will happen in this spark program?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I came across the example below:

```py
lines = sc.textFile("some_file.txt") //line_1

lineswithFriday = lines.filter(lambda line: line.startwith("Friday")) //line_2

lineswithFriday.first(); //line_3
```

It also says

> spark scans the file only until it finds the first line starting with
>   `friday`. It does not need to go through entire file.

My question is: does it mean spark will load each line one by one in memory, see if it starts with `Friday` and if yes stop there?

Say `line_1` created three partitions based on cores and input blocks. `line_2` will do the computation through separate worker thread on each cores.
On `line_3`, as soon as any worker finds a line starting with `Friday` it will stop there?

Comment: >On line_3 , as soon as any worked finds first line starting with Friday it will stop there ?
Executors will finish their tasks and they would not stop in the middle of the task execution. Of the returned result set, the first occurrence is taken. For more details try: `lineswithFriday.first().explain` and for detailed execution plan try: `lineswithFriday.first().explain(True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first() and take(n) can be optimized if used on their own.

There is no mechanism in terms of "inter process communication" within Spark allowing executors to terminate prematurely because the continued processing of results would be considered superfluous. That would lead to all sorts of issues architecturally speaking.

Comment: You mean even if a thread finds instance of line starting with `Friday`, it will continue to scan the complete file ? If that is right statement I quoted from google `spark scans the file only until it finds the first line starting with  friday. It does not need to go through entire file.` is not correct ?

Comment: Second point :  if there are three threads/process running on each core , how first result will be determined from the result retuned by three threads ?

Comment: You will not scan a file but partitions of a file. Once underway task must complete. For situations without filter correct though. Is optimization.

Comment: The results will be returned to driver along with partition id. The first will return the first value in a list with lowest partition id. How else could it work?

Comment: It’s all about parallelism. Your optimization idea would mean sort of sequential processing. Which is not Spark.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by `For situations without filter correct though. Is optimization` ?

Comment: If I want first() with no filter or take(n) where n is small value. Then ⚡️ can do what you stated. Eg look at first partition and see if data has enough data and then go to next partition. Ie optimization. But how often do we want that?